# MySQL Table Design for teams with limited number of members

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to design a database which contains a set of teams, each of which can have up to 5 members. The max may change, but 5 is fine for this question. Currently it is built in mysql and structured as follows:

`Table- Teams
  - teamid - Primary Key
  - [search criteria 1]
  - [search criteria 2]
  - [search criteria 3]
  - [other data]`

`Table- Accounts
  - accountid - Primary Key
  - [other data]`

`Table - Account Memberships
  - teamid - Primary Key, Foreign Key (Teams.teamid)
  - accountid - Primary Key, Foreign Key (Accounts.accountid)`

The system will search for a Team with exact matches on the 3 criteria. If it finds one or more matches that are not yet full, it will add the user to the first match. Otherwise, it will create a new team with the specified criteria and add the user as the first member.

I know how to write queries to search for the teams, and to count members in a team. I am worried, however, that if several users attempt this operation at the same time, I will get teams with an incorrect number of members. i.e. 2 users might search for the same criteria, and end up being placed as the 5th and 6th members of the same team.

Is there a way I can write my queries or restructure my database design to prevent race conditions and/or perform both the member count and member update atomically?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `LOCK TABLES` then read it, insert whatever you want, and then `UNLOCK TABLES`. This way several processes will wait for each other to finish before reading and inserting themselves and the race will be averted.

Comment: I took a look at the LOCK TABLES documentation, and this is what I came up with:

`LOCK TABLES teams READ, teammemberships WRITE;

SELECT teams.*, count(teammemberships.teamid) as membercount
FROM teams
LEFT JOIN teammemberships
ON (teams.teamid = teammemberships.teamid)
WHERE [criteria] 
GROUP BY teams.teamid
HAVING membercount < 5;`,

#Pick appropriate result in code,

`INSERT INTO teammemberships (accountid, teamid) VALUES ('[account id]', '[selected team]');

UNLOCK TABLES;`

The only problem here is that other attempted writes to teams fail instead of blocking. Any way around that?

Answer (score 0):

uri2x's answer got me googling in some new places, and I found a query that will do what I want in one action:

`INSERT INTO teammemberships (accountid, teamid) 
    SELECT '[account id]', teams.teamid
    FROM teams
    LEFT JOIN teammemberships
    ON (teams.teamid = teammemberships.teamid)
    WHERE [search criteria]
    GROUP BY teams.teamid
    HAVING count(teammemberships.teamid) < 5
    LIMIT 1;`

The only remaining problem with this query is if an account is trying to join a second team, and their current team is the one returned by that select, they will get a duplicate primary key error instead of being added to the next available team. For now I am limiting users to a single team, so that should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can write my queries or restructure my database design to prevent race conditions and/or perform both the member count and member update atomically?

Don't use `LOCK TABLES`, use `Engine=InnoDB`.

If you need to update two tables, do

```
BEGIN;
UPDATE table1 ...;
UPDATE table2 ...;
COMMIT;
```

and check for errors at each step -- deadlocks and other errors could occur.

If you also need a `SELECT` in the transaction, you probably need `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.